# Algorithm for calculating a distance between 2 3-dimensional points?

Tags: c#

I have two 3-D points.
Example:

```
float[] point1 = new float[3] {1.3919023, 6.12837912, 10.391283};
float[] point2 = new float[3] {48.3818, 38.38182, 318.381823};
```

Anyone an idea for an algorithm to calculate the distance in float between the points?

Comment: We'll let you know as soon as Wikipedia's blackout ends.

Comment: If the community couldn't answer this without googling then the world is doomed. Which reminds me: why didn't you google this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Euclidean distance between two 3D points is:

```
float deltaX = x1 - x0;
float deltaY = y1 - y0;
float deltaZ = z1 - z0;

float distance = (float) Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);
```

And in N dimensions (untested and vulnerable to overflow):

```
float DistanceN(float[] first, float[] second) {
  var sum = first.Select((x, i) => (x - second[i]) * (x - second[i])).Sum();
  return Math.Sqrt(sum);
}
```

**Edit:** I much prefer the `Zip` solution posted by dasblinkenlight below!

Comment: @JohnBoker: Fixed, thanks.  Also this question has been asked MANY times here on SO....

Comment: I prefer yours. On my machine (excluding overhead) it takes 60ms, while the linq solution takes 541 (for about 4 million calculations). I do agree that linq is quite elegant, but it's also expensive. For my use, I prefer the good old classic approach. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 20):

In C# with LINQ you can do this:

```
var dist = Math.Sqrt(point1.Zip(point2, (a, b) => (a - b)*(a - b)).Sum());
```

This sums up squared pairwise differences between individual coordinates, and returns the arithmetic square root of the sum.

**EDIT :** This solution works for any number of dimensions greater or equal to one (thanks to Austin Salonen for pointing it out).

Comment: Very nice n-dimensional solution

Comment: this looks awesome single line :D did you test to verify it works or not?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG When sizes of `point1` and `point2` match, it has no other choice except producing a square root of the sum of squared pairwise differences :-)

Answer (score 10):

[image]

`float distance=(float) Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point1[0]-point2[0],2) + Math.Pow(point1[1]-point2[1],2) + Math.Pow(point1[2]-point2[2],2))`

Answer (score 4):

Like 2D but with one more coordinate:

```
P1(x1, y1, z1); P2(x2, y2, z2)

d = SquareRootOf((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) + (z1-z2)*(z1-z2));
```

Obviously not written down in C# but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two points:
P1 = (x1, y1, z1)
P2 = (x2, y2, z2)
distance is `SQRT((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2)`

So you could use

```
float deltax = point2[0] - point1[0];
float deltay = point2[1] - point1[1];
float deltaz = point2[2] - point1[2];
float distance = (float) Math.Sqrt(
    (deltax * deltax) +
    (deltay * deltay) +
    (deltaz * deltaz));
```