# How to select all items in a radious in xyz space?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I have a `List` of `string`s formated like `{itemname}-{x}-{y}-{z}` (`x`, `y`, `z` are `typeof(int)` ). I have a point in 3d `xyz` space. I want using LINQ get all `List` items that are in some radious `R` (`typeof(int)`) from my point. How to do such thing with LINQ?

Answer (score 4):

I would split this into two tasks:

- Parsing the string into a more useful format
- Filtering by distance

So your query would be something like:

```
var query = values.Select(text => ItemPoint.Parse(text))
                  .Where(item => item.DistanceFrom(point) < radius);
```

(If you really need to get back to the text form, you could store it in the item when you parse it and have another `Select` call afterwards.)

Now you've got easily separable methods to write: `ItemPoint.Parse(string)` and `ItemPoint.DistanceFrom(Point)`. If you have problems with either of *those* methods, create another question giving more details, but LINQ will probably be irrelevant.

(For the parsing part, you might want to consider using `string.Split`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant part for the LINQ stuff:

```
// List of strings formated like {itemname}-{x}-{y}-{z}
List<string> test = new List<string>
{
    "name1-1-1-2",
    "name2-0-1-2",
    "name3-0-0-3"
};

var res = test
    .Select(tmp =>
        {
            string[] items = tmp.Split('-');
            return new
                {
                    x = int.Parse(items[1]),
                    y = int.Parse(items[2]),
                    z = int.Parse(items[3])
                };
        })
    .Where(tmp => (tmp.x + tmp.y + tmp.z) < 4)  // Insert the right math formula here.
    .ToList();
```

For the actual math formula, just google or search SO for it: [Algorithm for calculating a distance between 2 3-dimensional points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914669/algorithm-for-calculating-a-distance-between-2-3-dimensional-points)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can do it by constructing instances of an anonymous type to group coordinates and unparsed values until the `Where` clause, and then chopping off the coordinates to get the unparsed values back.

```
var itemPoints = new List<string> {
    "quick-1-2-3"
,   "brown-11-22-13"
,   "fox-10-42-33"
,   "jumps-19-23-31"
};
int x0=2, y0=1, z0=0, rSquare = 25;
var itemNames = itemPoints.Select(
    s => {
        var tt = s.Split('-');
        return new {
            Unparsed = s
        ,   x = int.Parse(tt[1])
        ,   y = int.Parse(tt[2])
        ,   z = int.Parse(tt[3])
        };
    }
).Where(p => (p.x-x0)*(p.x-x0)+(p.y-y0)*(p.y-y0)+(p.z-z0)*(p.z-z0) < rSquare)
.Select(p => p.Unparsed)
.ToList();
```

The distance formula squares both sides of the [Cartesian distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points) to avoid the costs of taking a square root.