# Latitude-longitude distance in 3 dimension space

Tags: c#, matlab, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems

I am implementing an algorithm to calculate distance between two objects (points) on the some custom map. However, the standard distance-formula, for example, implemented in this post [AnotherPostOnStackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366408/calculating-distance-between-two-latitude-and-longitude-geocoordinates)
calculate distance between **(lat1,lon1) and (lat2,lon2) in some 2d-space.** I mean that it takes Ox and Oz but **doesn't pay attention to Oy.**  See picture. 
[image]

I wonder what if my objects also placed in different Oy, i mean Object_1 (10,10, 2)  - earth and Object_2 (10,10, 20) - sky. How should i add calculation of distance by Oy too?

I want to use the following approach: 
Calculate distance between (lat1,lon1) and (lat2,lon2) normally, then change this values to simple (x,y) coordinates and find **Euclidean distance.** 
But then how to convert  distance((lat1,lon1),(lat2,lon2)) to coordinates?

My inputs : **double lat1, double lon1, int kilometersFromEarthFixedPoint**.

> Sample : object_1 : (43.222015, 76.851248, 5)
>
> Sample : object_2 : (51.160523, 71.470356, 2)

It means that this two objects are above the normal earth-point 0 such 0+2 and 0+5.

Expected output : miles\km

> 214 km (sample too)

**Should i ask this question in mathematics? And does this task contains the correct initial conditions?**

Comment: Maybe you could use this information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914669/algorithm-for-calculating-a-distance-between-2-3-dimensional-points

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Do you want the shortest distance between two points in space? The shortest great circle distance not moving through earth?