# How to index nearby 3D points on the fly?

Tags: algorithm, indexing, 3d, geometry, physics

In physics simulations (for example n-body systems) it is sometimes necessary to keep track of which particles (points in 3D space) are close enough to interact (within some cutoff distance d) in some kind of index.  However, particles can move around, so it is necessary to update the index, ideally on the fly without recomputing it entirely.  Also, for efficiency in calculating interactions it is necessary to keep the list of interacting particles in the form of tiles: a tile is a fixed size array (eg 32x32) where the rows and columns are particles, and almost every row-particle is close enough to interact with almost every column particle (and the array keeps track of which ones actually do interact).

What algorithms may be used to do this?

Here is a more detailed description of the problem:

1. Initial construction: Given a list of points in 3D space (on the order of a few thousand to a few million, stored as array of floats), produce a list of tiles of a fixed size (NxN), where each tile has two lists of points (N row points and N column points), and a boolean array NxN which describes whether the interaction between each row and column particle should be calculated, and for which:

   a. every pair of points p1,p2 for which distance(p1,p2) < d is found in at least one tile and marked as being calculated (no missing interactions), and

   b. if any pair of points is in more than one tile, it is only marked as being calculated in the boolean array in at most one tile (no duplicates),

   and also the number of tiles is relatively small if possible (but this is less important than being able to update the tiles efficiently)
2. Update step: If the positions of the points change *slightly* (by much less than d), update the list of tiles in the fastest way possible so that they still meet the same conditions a and b  (this step is repeated many times)

It is okay to keep any necessary data structures that help with this, for example the bounding boxes of each tile, or a spatial index like a quadtree.  It is probably too slow to calculate all particle pairwise distances for every update step (and in any case we only care about particles which are close, so we can skip most possible pairs of distances just by sorting along a single dimension for example). Also it is probably too slow to keep a full (quadtree or similar) index of all particle positions.  On the other hand is perfectly fine to construct the tiles on a regular grid of some kind.  The density of particles per unit volume in 3D space is roughly constant, so the tiles can probably be built from (essentially) fixed size bounding boxes.

To give an example of the typical scale/properties of this kind of problem, suppose there is 1 million particles, which are arranged as a [random packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_close_pack) of spheres of diameter 1 unit into a cube with of size roughly 100x100x100.  Suppose the cutoff distance is 5 units, so typically each particle would be interacting with `(2*5)**3` or ~1000 other particles or so.  The tile size is 32x32. There are roughly 1e+9 interacting pairs of particles, so the minimum possible number of tiles is ~1e+6.  Now assume each time the positions change, the particles move a distance around 0.0001 unit in a random direction, but always in a way such that they are at least 1 unit away from any other particle and the typical density of particles per unit volume stays the same.  There would typically be many millions of position update steps like that.  The number of newly created pairs of interactions per step due to the movement is (back of the envelope) `(10**2 * 6 * 0.0001 / 10**3) * 1e+9 = 60000`, so one update step can be handled in principle by marking 60000 particles as non-interacting in their original tiles, and adding at most 60000 new tiles (mostly empty - one per pair of newly interacting particles).  This would rapidly get to a point where most tiles are empty, so it is definitely necessary to combine/merge tiles somehow pretty often - but how to do it without a full rebuild of the tile list?

P.S. It is probably useful to describe how this differs from the typical spatial index (eg octrees) scenario: a. we only care about grouping close by points together into tiles, not looking up which points are in an arbitrary bounding box or which points are closest to a query point - a bit closer to clustering that querying and b. the density of points in space is pretty constant  and c. the index has to be updated very often, but most moves are tiny

Comment: are you looking for pre-built algorithms that do this or are looking for approach ideas? Not sure about pre-existing solutions for such problems (might need to find similar problems). Rudimentary level, feels like you can DYI by breaking it down (1) calculating 3D distances between points that move or in a closed space out of all possible points, (2) mapping that info to your tiles data structure (which is a different problem than the algorithm I feel), (3) keeping the info updated on some state change (particle movement?). https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914780/2361131 was duplicate for #1 maybe

Comment: @gawkface Thanks - Ideas for how to approach would be nice, not expecting a prebuilt algorithm.  One note - all points move every step, they just don’t move far

Comment: @gawkface About the answer you linked - calculating pairwise distances is not a problem, but there are far too many possible pairs (around 1e+12).  So any algorithm would have to either calculate distances only when a point is about to hop from one tile to another (and then only with a few points which are already known to be nearby), or assign points to tiles based only on their coordinates but not distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure my reasoning is sound, but here's an idea:

Divide your space into a grid of 3d cubes, like this in three dimensions:

[image]

The cubes have a side length of `d`. Then do the following:

1. Assign all points to all cubes in which they're contained; this is fast since you can derive a point's cube from just their coordinates
2. Now check the following:

   - Mark all points in the top left of your cube as colliding; they're less than `d` apart. Further, every "quarter cube" in space is only the top left quarter of exactly one cube, so you won't check the same pair twice.
   - Check fo collisions of type `(p, q)`, where `p` is a point in the top left quartile, and `q` is a point *not* in the top left quartile. In this way, you will check collision between every two points again at most once, because very pair of quantiles is checked exactly once.

Since every pair of points is either in the same quartile or in neihgbouring quartiles, they'll be checked by the first or the second algorithm. Further, since points are approximately distributed evenly, your runtime is much less than n^2 (n=no points); in aggregate, it's k^2 (k = no points per quartile, which appears to be approximately constant).

In an update step, you only need to check:

- if a point crossed a boundary of a box, which should be fast since you can look at one coordinate at a time, and box' boundaries are a simple multiple of `d/2`
- check for collisions of the points as above

To create the tiles, divide the space into a second grid of (non-overlapping) cubes whose width is chosen s.t. the average count of centers between two particles that almost interact with each other that fall into a given cube is less than the width of your tiles (i.e. 32). Since each particle is expected to interact with 300-500 particles, the width will be much smaller than  `d`.

Then, while checking for interactions in step 1 & 2, assigne particle interactions to these new cubes according to the coordinates of the center of their interaction. Assign one tile per cube, and mark interacting particles assigned to that cube in the tile. Visualization:

[image]

Further optimizations might be to consider the distance of a point's closest neighbour within a cube, and derive from that how many update steps are needed at least to change the collision status of that point; then ignore that point for this many steps.

Comment: “ Assign all points to all cubes in which they're contained; this is fast since ….”  I think this is in the right track - almost any practical algorithm would have to do that.  I’m not sure if your answer describes how to assign point to tiles though - is each cube a tile?  (including overlapping cubes?). Perhaps you could expand on your idea.  Thanks!

Comment: I started with that, but realized that your tiles are of limited size, and adjusted the answer slightly; the result isn't that pretty. Are they limited? If yes, You could create one tile per cube, and just assign points to tiles according to which cubes they are contained in, and mark collisions in the tiles assigned to cubes in which they're detected.

Comment: If no, you could create a second grid of non-overlapping cubes with smaller size (as small as needed depending on the amount of points each tile can contain), and assign one tile per cube. Tthen assign two points to a tile <=> their points of collision (half the distance between them) is within a given cube.

Comment: Since you're only checking on collison of a small subset of point-pairs, that shouldn't explode i.t.o. complexity either.

Comment: I wanted to clarify one thing btw, typically each tile would be 32x32 or a similar size, but each particle would interact with 300-500 other particles.  In other words if d is the cutoff distance for interactions, a cube of size d (in which every particle interacts with every other). would need (300/32)^2 or ~100 tiles or so.  Particles can interact without colliding - the cutoff distance is much longer than the typical spacing between particles.  Not sure I’m how that affects things.  Perhaps the regular grid of cubes needs to have cubes which are roughly tile-sized, not cutoff sized?

Comment: But particle interactions are between pairs, right? You don't need to know the set of all interacting particle with a given particle?

Comment: Tiles are limited by what is most efficient for hardware, but any larger tile can be represented as smaller eg 64x64=four 32x32. Using any sizes smaller than 32 takes exactly as long per tile as using the full 32.  (This is running on GPU, so 32 comes from the warp size)

Comment: the high level goal is to put all interacting pair of particles in tiles.  The tiles may not be fully occupied, and there may be duplicates (which are marked as duplicates in all but one tile) but there should be no missing interactions

Comment: I've expanded the explanation of my idea. The question is how large the variance is of the particle density; if it's too large, it might be inefficient, since most tiles will have to be mostly empty (so that if density is high at some spots, the tiles aren't filled up). You might also just use the first cubes and increase tile size. I don't know much about GPU programming.

Comment: “You don't need to know the set of all interacting particle with a given particle?”. Kind of yes - need to know the set of all interacting pairs of particles; okay to run calculations on a superset of that (ie between particles which are too far apart) just not a subset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239661/discussion-between-nearoo-and-alex-i).

Comment: An example of a correct (bit inefficient) algorithm is to sort all particles along one axis, assign them sequentially to block of size 32, and form tiles from any pair of blocks which are closer than d along that axis.  This ignores the fact that most particles in a typical tile would be too far because they are far apart along the other two axes - it would calculate too many interactions but wouldn’t miss any

Comment: Variation in density is not huge; maybe +-10% or so?   Absolutely chat, but it would have to be in ~8 hours for me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following algorithm. E.g we have cube 1x1x1 and the cutoff distance is 0.001

1. Let's choose three base anchor points: (0,0,0) (0,1,0) (1,0,0)
2. Associate array of size 1000 ( 1 / 0.001) with each anchor point
3. Add three numbers into each regular point. We will store the distance between the given point and each anchor point inside these fields
4. At the same time this distance will be used as an index in an array inside the anchor point. E.g. 0.4324 means index 432.
5. Let's store the set of points inside of each three arrays
6. Calculate distance between the regular point and each anchor point every time when update point
7. Move point between sets in arrays during the update

The given structures will give you an easy way to find all closer points: it is the intersection between three sets. And we choose these sets based on the distance between point and anchor points.

In short, it is the intersection between three spheres. Maybe you need to apply additional filtering for the result if you want to erase the corners of this intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Barnes-Hut algorithm or something similar.  A simulation in 2D would use a quadtree data structure to store particles, and a 3D simulation would use an octree.

The benefit of using a a tree structure is that it stores the particles in a way that nearby particles can be found quickly by traversing the tree, and far-away particles are in traversal paths that can be ignored.

Wikipedia has a good description of the algorithm:
The Barnes–Hut tree
In a three-dimensional n-body simulation, the Barnes–Hut algorithm recursively divides the n bodies into groups by storing them in an octree (or a quad-tree in a 2D simulation). Each node in this tree represents a region of the three-dimensional space. The topmost node represents the whole space, and its eight children represent the eight octants of the space. The space is recursively subdivided into octants until each subdivision contains 0 or 1 bodies (some regions do not have bodies in all of their octants). There are two types of nodes in the octree: internal and external nodes. An external node has no children and is either empty or represents a single body. Each internal node represents the group of bodies beneath it, and stores the center of mass and the total mass of all its children bodies.

[demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20140413142523/http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/sameera/demos/BNtree/)